# Perl - Array reference, using strict

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, strict

I have the following code:

```
my @array = ('a', 'b', 'c');

my $region = \@array;  # Returns an array reference
my $Value = ${@{$region}}[3];
```

I am using strict;

This code passed smoothly in Perl v5.8.6, and now that I installed  v5.10.1, I get a runtime error:

> Can't use string ("4") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at ...

I changed the code to the following, and that solved the issue:

```
my @array = ('a', 'b', 'c');

my $region = \@Array;
my @List = @{$region};
my $Value = $List[3];
```

my question is, what's wrong with the previous way? What has changed between these two versions?
What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Gal

Comment: Also what I think the problem is... that your region contains 4 elements, than @{$region} is evaluated in a list context which returns 4 and your call becomes: $Value = ${'4'}[3] which produces the error

Comment: Why do you keep referencing the 4th element in a list which is three elements long in the code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`${@{$region}}[3]` was never the correct way to access an arrayref.  I'm not quite sure what it does mean, and I don't think Perl is either (hence the different behavior in different versions of Perl).

The correct ways are explained in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References):

```
my $Value = ${$region}[3]; # This works with any expression returning an arrayref
my $Value = $$region[3];   # Since $region is a simple scalar variable,
                           # the braces are optional
my $Value = $region->[3];  # This is the way I would do it
```

Comment: The new behavior is correct; the block after the `$` should get scalar context.  Older perl versions would erroneously promote the array to an array reference.  But I thought this was going through a deprecation cycle - looks like that was done for `@array->[]` but not `${@array}[]` :(

Comment: `${ @{$region} }[3]` is `${ scalar(@{$region}) }[3]`. It's equivalent to `$0[3]`, `$1[3]`, `$2[3]` or similar, depending on the number of elements in `@$region`.

Comment: @Jared Ng, All *3*? Only two ways were presented. If you consider adding parens, then there are far more than 3. `${$region}[3]`, `${region}->[3]` and `($region)->[3]`, for starters.

Comment: @ysth, Those curlies don't form a block.

Comment: @ysth, as best I can tell, `${@array}[]` didn't get a deprecation cycle cause it always worked correctly. (Worked in 5.10, don't have 5.8 anymore) `@array->[]` was deprecated in 5.12 and fixed in 5.14.

Comment: ikegami: yes, they do.  `print for %{ my %x; @x{"a".."j"} = reverse 0..9; \%x }`

Comment: @ysth, hum, My test must have been bad, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
my @array = ('a', 'b', 'c');
my $region = \@array;
my $Value = $$region[1];
print $Value;
```

Output:

```
b
```

Comment: Why exactly did this get a downvote? It's a perfectly valid method.